# .NET set collection with O(1) lookup?

Tags: .net, collections

I have a bunch of unique integers and I want to decide as quickly as possible, if a given integer can be found among them or not.

The documentation for [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) says that checking if a value is present in a dictionary approaches an O(1) operation. So if I use something like a `Dictionary<int, bool>`, and check if a given integer value is present then my problem is solved. This solution however needlessly stores the bool values for my keys and I suspect that there has to be a more straightforward way to do this.

Is there a built in solution for this problem in the .NET framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) as of .NET 3.5 - that's probably what you want.

Comment: I had concerns about HashSet<T>, but they are addressed by this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562141/o1-maintained-in-hashset-lookups-when-using-alternative-comparator